# Qt in VS2010 - Can't use the Objects create by the Designer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm using Qt with Visual Studio 2010 but I have a doubt.
Whenever I use the Qt Designer to create a GUI, when compiling in Visual I have no access to the Objects auto created by the designer, like the buttons, listboxes etc...
What should I do in order to use them ?

My point is, I can't create events, slots, signals, etc, cause it seems this objects do not exist in my main.cpp and my mainclass.cpp.

Thanks guys !

I'm using VS 2010 with QT 4.8.0.

```
#include <QListWidget.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ui_ratagbc.h"

class dasm: QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    dasm(void);
    ~dasm(void);
    int DAsm(FILE *,int);
private:
    Ui::RataGBCClass *ui;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the GUI in your code, include the result from running the `uic` tool.  Create a class, and have as a member variable an instance of the class that `uic` generated, it is in the Ui namespace.

```
#include "ui_MyGUI.h" //automatically generated by uic tool

class MyClass : public QDialog //or whatever type of GUI you made
    {
    Q_OBJECT //this macro flags your class for the moc tool
    //other variables and functions
    Ui::MyGUI ui;
    };
```

You get access through this 'ui' object:
`ui.label->setText("New label text set in source file");`

In your constructor, call `ui.setupUi(this)`

Note the Q_OBJECT macro - if you're defining signals and slots or stuff like that, you need the Q_OBJECT there to flag the class for the `moc` tool to recognize it.

Edit to answer followup question in comments:
It sounds like what you want to do is use the signal/slot system.  In your class definition, include the following:

```
class MyClass
{
//other stuff
public slots:
void customSlot(){/* your actions here */}
//other stuff
};
```

Then someplace else, commonly in the constructor or an initialization function, inclue this line:

```
connect(ui.button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(customSlot()));
```

The `moc` tool handles the bulk of the setup.  Your custom slot will then be triggered when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks man, it really worked. I have one last doubt. For example, if I want to create an event, for example, when clicking a button, what should I do ? I mean, I know how to do that, I just want to know where should I place the codes, like the slots and signals. Thanks !

Comment: Edited above to answer the follow-up

Comment: You can also use automatic slot connections for that. I use this method almost always for uis I create in the designer. See here: http://qtway.blogspot.com/2010/08/automatic-connections-using-qt-signals.html

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the tips ! But now I'm getting the following error when I try to use the slots keyword: moc_eventos.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall eventos::teste(void)" (?teste@eventos@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl eventos::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@eventos@@CAXPAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

Comment: It sounds like you didn't include the moc_Filename.cpp file (the output of the `moc` tool) in your project.

Comment: No, I can see the file there. When doing the nmake process, I got a few errors. Does that have something to do with it ? How should I proceed now ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code (in an edit or something)?

Comment: I have edit my code. I'm getting this error: 1>dasm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall dasm::DAsm(struct _iobuf *,int)" (?DAsm@dasm@@QAEHPAU_iobuf@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall dasm::dasm(void)" (??0dasm@@QAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\Magaly\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RataGBC\\RataGBC.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: In your .cpp file, are you providing the body of the `int DAsm(FILE*,int)` function?  Can you post it?